# VScode rejects keyboard shortcut CTRL + ù

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

I am working on OS Ubuntu 22.04 running inside a Virtualbox VM hosted in a windows 10 OS.

Inside the VM, it seems that my VScode has reset some of the user-defined keyboard shortcuts I have previously set.

So I want to re-define them.

I want to change the keyboard shortcut of "Toggle Line Comment", which is set from <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ù</kbd> ( currently <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> is assigned by the system to "redo", and that is OK ).

[image]

So I click on the pencil icon of "Toggle Line Comment",

press the keys combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ù</kbd>

[image]

"ù" gets interpreted as "[Backslash]"

press enter

but then I still see assigned <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> (as if the change was rejected); and from some tests I did, that one is the only combination that manages to toggle comment lines.

I have tryed to restart VScode but nothing changes, I cannot edit the settings from the UI.

So I have tryed to edit them from the `keybindings.json`

```
tommaso@tommaso-VirtualBox02:~$ sudo locate keybindings.json    
/home/tommaso/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json

tommaso@tommaso-VirtualBox02:~$ vim /home/tommaso/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json
```

And the content of the opened file is

```
[    
    {    
        "key": "ctrl+alt+[Backslash]",    
        "command": "editor.action.blockComment",    
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"    
    },    
    {    
        "key": "ctrl+shift+a",    
        "command": "-editor.action.blockComment",    
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"    
    },    
    {    
        "key": "ctrl+shift+7",    
        "command": "-editor.action.commentLine",    
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"    
    },    
    {    
        "key": "ctrl+[Backslash]",    
        "command": "editor.action.commentLine"    
    }    
]
```

It is indeed strange that the last `{}` entry I have added via the UI is missing the `"when"` key.

Anyway I have edited the content to

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+[Backslash]",
        "command": "editor.action.blockComment",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+a",
        "command": "-editor.action.blockComment",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+7",
        "command": "-editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+[Backslash]",
        "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }
]
```

saved,

restarted VScode

but again, the "toggle line comment" gets activated only by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.

The strange thing is that the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ù</kbd>, that is

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+[Backslash]",
        "command": "editor.action.blockComment",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }
```

works fine.

It is like VS code cannot load changes from keybindings.json .

What can be blocking the edit?

Comment: What's the connection between blackslashes and `ù` on your keyboard? It's not clear to me.

Comment: the `ù` is interpreted by VScode as `[Backslash]`, it is maybe weird but it works  for the shortcut CTRL + ALT + ù . Why should not it work for  CTRL + ù

Comment: Edits will be blocked from the kebindings UI editor if the keybindings.json file has unsaved changes (you'll get a popup notification saying so).

Comment: that is not the case, I actually got the popup once when I was doing things wrong.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. That kind of information is the kind that will save people wasted time trying to understand your problem.

Comment: Same here, `Enter` is now interpreted as `F3` and some of my shortcuts are screwed since last update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From another machine having the same key VScode shortcut configuration, and having the shotcuts properly working on VScode, I accessed the content of keybinding.json, and it is the following

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+[Backslash]",
        "command": "editor.action.blockComment",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+a",
        "command": "-editor.action.blockComment",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+[Backslash]",
        "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+7",
        "command": "-editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }
]
```

It is exactly the same content of the one on the other machine, for which it was not working properly.

So the problem is machine-related.

So the end I have set the key combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>à</kbd> for the toggle line comment, and it is OK.

I think the problem is somehow linked to how VScode interprets a key:

I have an italian keyboard having a key which contains "§" and "ù", but VS code somehow interprets it as "[Backslash]".

Once again I want to underline that it is strange to me that

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ù</kbd>

is correctly got as change by VScode, while

2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ù</kbd>

is rejected ( the UI swithces the combination automatically to "ctrl"+"y", while on the keybindings.json it is actually written "ctrl+[Backslash]" )

even if in both cases 1) and 2), "ù" is interpreted as "[Backslash]".

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would do this like so:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+\\",
        "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+y",
        "command": "-editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
]
```

Comment: it does not work